# Facebook wont detect my IMAGE

Tags: image, facebook, facebook-graph-api

hey guys i am having a problem that i see others with online but i am yet to find a fix for my website.

facebook not detecting my images as of a couple of hours ago, i tried disabling hotlinks in cloudflare, tried fb debuger and scrapping tool etc no solution.

example if you try to share this page, no picture appears: http://www.yardhype.com/12-year-old-jamaican-girl-wins-master-chef-junior-competition/

**ERROR message** 
"Provided og:image URL, ........testsite/wblob/5433A6CF57A599/2803/3DF62/w3l6_ERf2C3ADvxqhgccQg/jasmin.png could not be downloaded because it exceeded the maximum allowed sized of 8Mb."

**the image is not over 8mb
ALso correct url is shown in the raw tag area**

Answer (score 0):

When I opened that link http://www.yardhype.com/12-year-old-jamaican-girl-wins-master-chef-junior-competition/ I don't see the image regardless; I opened up Chrome's debugger and saw this:

```
A Parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script,
http://ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/nexp/dok3v=85b614c0f6/cloudflare.min.js, 
is invoked via document.write. The network request for this script MAY be 
blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor network 
connectivity. If blocked in this page load, it will be confirmed in a
subsequent console message.See 
https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more details.
```

So the way that page is displaying the image is likely not up to standards.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, while i don't fully understand all that you write, i must say the image loads for me fine! My network connection is great!

Comment: also i enabled all-in-one seo and scroll down on post editor for new post, select SOCIAL SETTINGS tab, then select the image that appears, then update the post..... After doing this the picture appears when trying to share to fb.... NOTE: the most recent posts show IMAGE for fb now because of this temp fix i did however no IMAGE still wont appear for http://www.yardhype.com/12-year-old-jamaican-girl-wins-master-chef-junior-competition/ .... if i dont do the aio image select on other posts i wont get the fb IMAGE... REMEMBER all worked well for years until couple hrs ago

Comment: The summary of my answer is that the web page is using certain tricks to display the image, and anything could have changed in the last few hours to break things; Facebook APIs, browser versions, original web site changes in how the page is formatted; the real reason your code is not working is that particular web page is dynamically writing out the final URI where the image really is.